# Filter by default

Tags: bash, shell, interactive

I'd like to configure my interactive shell (e.g. *bash*), so that by default all command output will be piped to some filter, e.g. *less*.
i.e., if I type

```
# make
```

it will automatically be interpreted as

```
# make | less
```

Note 1: *less* is not a very good filter for my purpose, it's just an example. I'll look for another or write my own filter if I only knew how to eventually put it to use.

Note 2: The solution must be robust, working well with all commands and scripts no matter how complex and what sub-shells they might run.

Comment: When you say "all commands", do you mean that you want this to happen even when the invoked command is an interactive program that expects to write to the terminal directly?

Comment: Assuming this is possible: I guess it will be difficult to implement a filter that will correctly handle the output of programs that use cursor positioning, e.g. `vi`. Some programs may behave differently if the output is connected to pipe instead of a terminal.

Comment: You might think you want this, but you really don't.  Even if you somehow manage it (which would probably require writing your own shell to replace bash), it would cause many times more problems than it would "solve".   And you'd be replacing the problem of "i don't want to have to remember to pipe my commands into `foo`" with "i don't want to have to have to remember to pipe my commands into `anti-foo`".    If less/more is the issue, then investigate your terminal's scroll-back options - many terminals can be configured for tens of thousands of lines of scrollback.

Comment: also, you'd have to define when, exactly, you wanted this auto-piping to occur: e.g. a) only on command lines without a pipe character; b) between each and every piped program on the command line; c) only after the final piped program on the command line; or d) some other ([DWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM)) time.       And, no matter how you defined it, your shell would still become some relative of auto-correct hell.